# ¿Cómo obtener valor seleccionado de ComboBox en Windows-Forms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, dropdownlist

Tengo este método por el cual me conecto a una base de datos en Access y obtengo los valores de la tabla "Empresas"

```
private DataTable GetData()
{
    try
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Empresas";
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conexión);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Empresas");
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

En base al `DataTable` que me devuelve este método, armo el `ComboBox`

```
void LOADComboUsuario()
{
    comboEmpresas.DataSource = GetData();
    comboEmpresas.ValueMember = "EM_Empresa";
    comboEmpresas.DisplayMember = "EM_Razon";
}
```

Es decir que en el combo yo pongo el Nro de empresa como `ValueMember` y el nombre de la empresa como `DisplayMember`.

Mi problema es que en el `selectedIndexChanged` del combo quiero guardar en un string el `ValueMember` que tiene ese ítem seleccionado.

Estoy usando esta sentencia:

```
string empresa_ = comboEmpresas.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Pero esto me está devolviendo el índice del combo en lugar del `SelectedValue`.

Dato curioso: Si en `DisplayMember` pongo el Nro de empresa ("EM_Empresa") muestra bien el valor en el combo, pero en el string sigue guardando el índice.

Alguien puede decirme qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Es raro que el `SelectedValue` este tomando el indice, a menos que el valor de `EM_Empresa` sea así como lo toma la variable y estes confundido, y si tomas el valor de `comboEmpresas.SelectedItem` que resultado obtienes?... También en ves de usar el evento `selectedIndexChanged` prueba usar este evento: `SelecctionChangeCommitted` y solo por curiosidad, invierte estas dos lineas: primero coloca `comboEmpresas.DisplayMember = "EM_Razon";` y luego `comboEmpresas.ValueMember = "EM_Empresa";` el **Nro** empresa estas seguro que es `EM_Empresa` ?

Comment: @J.Rodríguez gracias por tu ayuda! Marqué la respuesta de Horacio porque ese fue el problema que tenía. No se por qué motivo, al estar marcado el atributo "Sorted" ordena el combo alfabeticamente pero no ordena también los valores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En las propiedades del combo debe tener tildado "Sorted" = true, esto hace que ordene por el nombre de la empresa pero queda desordenado el valor.

Comment: Por favor, mira [answer] y tambien haz el [tour]. que tiene que ver esta respuesta con la pregunta?

Comment: En realidad el problema fue ese... las propiedades del `ComboBox` tenia el atributo "Sorted" en true, lo saqué y anduvo...

Comment: Horacio, ya que si da respueta a la pregunta, intenta mejorar la calidad de la respuesta añadiendo más informacion . mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b, Y qué mas información se necesita? respondió a la pregunta, y explicó el motivo, ¿qué mas de requiere?

Comment: @Luis bueno, por ejemplo una captura del listado de propiedades donde se modifica ese valor y un enlace a la documentación para ver qué implicaciones tiene. Para el usuario de esta pregunta está claro ya que lo aceptó pero para futuros usuarios quien sabe :P yo lo decía porque alguien la marcó como baja calidad. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo manejo por medio de tres pasos, el primero sería por medio de un metodo en la clase DAO que me permite realizar la consulta. Por ejemplo:

```
public DataTable RecuperarEstado()
    {
        string ComandoSQL = "SELECT * FROM estado_prestamo";
        DataTable datos = MiConexion.EjecutarSentencia(ComandoSQL);

        //Agrego nueva fila para evitar fila por defecto
        datos.Rows.Add(new object[] { 0, "Seleccionar" });

        //ordenar tabla
        DataView dv = datos.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = "id_estado_prestamo asc";
        DataTable tablaordenada = dv.ToTable();
        return tablaordenada;
    }
```

Posteriormente agrego los valores a mi ComboBox:

```
//combobox de estado
        cmb_Estado.DataSource = preDAO.RecuperarEstado();
        cmb_Estado.DisplayMember = "nombre_estado";
        cmb_Estado.ValueMember = "id_estado_prestamo";
```

Y por último recupero el valor mi selección:

```
preBO.Id_est_pres = Convert.ToInt16(cmb_Estado.SelectedValue);
```

Pd: preBO y preDAO son los objetos de mis clases.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte! El problema que tenía fue lo que comentó Horacio en la respuesta marcada. Voto tu respuesta ya que parece ser una buena solución igualmente. La tendré en cuenta a futuro!

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera, a mi me funciona, tengo una función que llena mi combobox, por lo que puedes usarlo para cualquier otro combo y enviar el nombre del DisplayMember y ValueMember dinamicamente:

```
    public static void LlenarCombobox(ComboBox cb, string DisplayMember, string ValueMember)
    {
        var lista = GenericServices<Sorteo>.ListarTodos().ToList();

        cb.DisplayMember = DisplayMember;
        cb.ValueMember = ValueMember;
        cb.DataSource = lista;
    }
```

Y lo uso de esta forma:

```
    private void frmListarSorteos_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        try
        {
            NSorteo.LlenarCombobox(cbSorteos, "NombreSorteo", "SorteoId");
            NSorteoReferencia.LlenarCombobox(cbSorteoRef, "NombreSorteo", "SorteoReferenciaId");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Mensaje del sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Entonces, como en el primer combobox, si tu quieres mostrar en un MessageBox por ejemplo el valor que se encuentra en la base de datos, en mi caso el nombre de un sorteo, haces lo siguiente para que te imprima ese texto traído de la BD y no un numero, que en mi caso vendría siendo el SorteoId:

```
    //Imprime el texto real contenido en DisplayMember
    MessageBox.Show(cbSorteos.GetItemText(cbSorteos.SelectedItem));

    //Imprime el valor de ValueMember, SorteoId en mi aplicación
    MessageBox.Show(cbSorteos.SelectedValue );
```

Espero mi respuesta te ayude en algo, saludos

Answer (score 1):

yo estoy trabajando con windows forms, y de esta forma los obtengo, en este caso la clave (ID) del elemento seleccionado.

```
    var sucursales = conn.ExecuteReader("select Id, Nombre from Sucursales where EmpresaID = @EmpresaID", new { EmpresaID = valor });
                DataTable td = new DataTable();
                td.Load(sucursales);

                cboSuc.DataSource = td;
                cboSuc.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
                cboSuc.ValueMember = "ID";
//**** de esta forma obtengo el valor del COMBOBOX, lo guardo en una variable tipo int**********
    int I d=    Convert.ToInt32(cboEmp.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte! El problema que tenía fue lo que comentó Horacio en la respuesta marcada. Voto tu respuesta ya que parece ser una buena solución igualmente. La tendré en cuenta a futuro!